# Owin Unauthorised when hosting more web apis inside IIS website

Tags: c#, api, oauth, signalr, owin

Let's describe my architecture, I have one root IIS WebSite, then Web Api where using Owin for authentication then AngularJS front-end and another Web Api to server this front end.
Look's like:

```
Website(root) -
  Auth(Web API Owin)
  Front-End(AngularJS) -
    Service(Web API)
```

My issue is following:
- I can get token from Web Api Owin app from front-end
- When I try to use this token against controllers on serving web api "Service" I got Unauthorised response

I have tried various combinations of configuration of web api auth, all sites are on the same machine, I don't use MachineKey in web.config.

The configuration is following:
Web Api Owin:

```
public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

        OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
    }
}
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Service Web Api:

```
public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }
    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

        OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

    }
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        // use cors with signalR
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true
                    // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                    // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                    // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                    // EnableJSONP = true
                };
                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
    }
}
```

I'm using my own OAuthProvider which looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly string _publicClientId;

    public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId)
    {
        if (publicClientId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
        }

        _publicClientId = publicClientId;
    }

    public override Task MatchEndpoint(OAuthMatchEndpointContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsTokenEndpoint && context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
        {
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "authorization" });
            context.RequestCompleted();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
        return base.MatchEndpoint(context);
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        if (!context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"))
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
        if (user.Roles != null && user.Roles.Count != 0)
            oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId).Aggregate((acc, r) => acc + ";" + r)));
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("TwoFactorExpiration", user.TwoFactorExpiration.ToString()));

        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }

    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
        {
            Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

            if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "userName", userName }
        };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have using SignalR on service web api as well.
All works nice and smothly if each web api has its own web site on IIS.

What am I doing wrong? I know there is something what I have missed. The intent is using one web api owin app for authorization many web apis, as you can see I defined there role-based authentication as well.

Thanks for any input.

Update 1:
When I'm trying debug my IIS web site via Visual Studio I'm getting following messages in debug window:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in System.Web.dll

...

w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)

w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'Get(Nullable`1 affiliateId, Nullable`1 date)'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction

w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=AffiliatesController.ExecuteAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)

w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance

w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=CorsMessageHandler.SendAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)

w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate

w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution, even your solution are on the same machine, you have to create machine key for your machine and attach it into yours web configs, follow Step 5 of this:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/

I still don't know why it's working when each web api has itself IIS web site.